# ASP.NET progressive page load

Tags: asp.net, pageload

I'm working on an ASP.NET web site, I've created a new page which loads a lot of data, therefore it takes a bit of time to load the whole page, but I'm going to load my page progressively, so that whenever user goes down, more details of page are loaded (something like google image search or facebook pages), what are my options?

Comment: http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: thanks, it looks fine, should I use web services for this technique?

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, what you're describing isn't progressive page loading - which actually refers to the browser's ability to render a page before it's finished downloading (i.e. before it's gotten to the `</html>` closing tag).

Anyway, obviously jQuery is your first and most obvious solution - define a simple web-service method (for which I strongly recommend using ASP.NET MVC and not WebForms) which is an AJAX call from your jQuery code. I recommend returning JSON which gives you greater flexibility in controlling the client rendering.

I strongly advise against loading more data on a window scroll event - it's a very bad user experience (i.e. the user expects to reach the bottom of the page, not to have it jump away). Instead I recommend having a big button that says "Load more").

I also recommend returning the first batch of results in the initial HTML returned by ASP.NET for the sake of clients that don't support scripting and any spiders. Plus it means the user doesn't have to wait for the page to be returned and then wait again for the AJAX call to complete.